# How to Avoid Jump Between Checked and Unchecked States

Tags: checkbox

I have custom checkboxes, and the content is jumping when I click between checked and unchecked states. How can I stop this from happening? Here's my code:

CSS:

```
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

label:before {
content: "";
display: inline-block;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
margin-right: 18px;
background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225);
border-radius:4px;
border:1px solid #cecece;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
content: "\2713";
font-size: 15px;
color: red;
text-align: center;
line-height: 15px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="lists[Fortune Daily]" />
<label for="checkbox1"><img class="list" src="http://email-media.s3.amazonaws.com/fortune/fortunef_55x50.png" /> <span>Fortune Daily</span>
</label>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Messing with check boxes via CSS/HTML is pretty awkward. I'd recommend going with a jQuery solution like http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettycheckboxes/

Comment: Thanks SRing! Unfortunately I need a CSS/HTML solution because the system this form will live in doesn't do well with JS...

Comment: Fair :) Check out Alexander's answer. He's got it.

Answer (score 1):

It's no problem to correct the jumping. See the below code:

```css
input[type=checkbox] {
display: none;
}

label {
  font-size: 15px;
  vertical-align: top;
}

label:before {
content: "\2713";
display: inline-block;
width: 16px;
height: 16px;
margin-right: 18px;
background-color: rgba(225, 225, 225);
border-radius:4px;
border:1px solid #cecece;
font-size: 15px;
color: white;
text-align: center;
line-height: 15px;
}

input[type=checkbox]:checked + label:before {
color: red;
}
```

```html
<input id="checkbox1" type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="lists[Fortune Daily]" />
<label for="checkbox1"><img class="list" src="http://email-media.s3.amazonaws.com/fortune/fortunef_55x50.png" /> <span>Fortune Daily</span>
</label>
```

However, I wouldn't recommend you to continue with this solution, because it's seems to be impossible to make a correct vertical alignment of the elements here. For example, instead of label with 'before' you could realize it by an outside div with `display:table` property and three inside element with `display:table-cell`. At least you will have a full control on elements' placement not dependent on font size.